# Best way to store player actions and movements and repeat them

Tags: libgdx, movement

I am developing a tile based game to help improve my skills, there will be an entity spawning and following the player, to get around the various obstacles around the map i think that the best way would be for the entity to simply shadow the players movements.

What is the best way to store the players action e.g. jump, move left/right etc.

Would there be an alternative better way for the entity to hunt down the player?

Comment: Would a bog-standard pathfinding solution like A* not serve your needs here?

Comment: Is "shadowing player" an essential part of your gameplay or do you simply want the entity to follow/chase player?

Comment: Too many possible ways to do this to get a single answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) and a [circular or regular buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852863/fixed-size-queue-which-automatically-dequeues-old-values-upon-new-enques).

The former encapsulates all the information you need to store a command (of your general design) as a single class instance, while the second allows you to limit the length of your history of commands so that you don't run out of memory.